# How to scale text relative to screen size?

Tags: android

I want to display some values on screen such that they occupy roughly the same percentage of screen area irrespective of display size or pixel density. How do I do that?

When I use `dp` or `sp` I get the following results for the same font size a tablet and on a phone.

One a 1280x768 4.7 inch phone:
[image: 1280x768 4.7 inch phone]

On a 1280x800 10 inch tablet:
[image: 1280x800 10 inch tablet]

Comment: Take a look at [Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

Comment: After reading that, the only solution I see is creating a separate XML for tablets. Is there no there way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to create different `layout` folder, for instance for devices like 7" tablet (600x1024 mdpi), you'll have to create the folder `res/layout-sw600dp/` and in there put the layout that you want to display on screens that has this screen-size and change for instance the `TextView` text size, position on the screen, etc...

I recommend you to read the [Support different screen sizes documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes), there's well explained how to do that.

Also you have other way to do that, it's better the first one, but I personally used this library and it worked well for me because the layout were not that big.

Test this [`SDP - a scalable size unit`](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) library, then you do now have to create different layouts *or yes deppends of your likes*

Comment: Thanks, will check it out. I would like to avoid maintaining separate XMLs as keeping them in sync will be additional work. BTW, what was your reason to not use separate XMLs?

Comment: Now I'm doing separate XMLs on my project though, but I also used that library and it really works... same layout in small / medium / big devices in only 1 layout, it's cool.

Comment: Is there anyway to kind of "inherit" one layout xml form other? That way, I can only override changes and let everything else be inherited from parent.

Comment: Don't get you sorry

Comment: You can go for adding sdp library by Intuit. I think another answer is saying the same.

Comment: @DeepPatel Check the time that I've posted my answer and check the time of him ;)

Comment: Dunno why downvoted, but who did, c'mon tell me why ;)

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I was talking about inheritance as in object oriented programming where the child class only overrides methods of the parent that it wants to change.  Similar concept is found in CSS styles. Style for div is overridden by style for a particular class which is intern overridden by style attributes specified directly in the tag. If such feature was supported, I was thinking of overriding only the font properties in the child layout. That way I don't have to replicate common changes in all layout files..

Answer (score 1):

Try using SDP library for mentioning dimens in your XML file.

After that there will be no need to prepare multiple layout files.

**Please check this [library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)**,
      *that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.*